# How to apply condition in relationship methods from controller?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three model MainCategory, Subcategory and Menu

Main category Model

```
protected $table="main_categories";

protected $fillable =['category'];

public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class,'maincategory_id');
}
```

Sub Category Model

```
protected $table="sub_categories";

protected $fillable =['category','maincategory_id'];

public function foods()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Menu::class,'subcategory_id');
}
```

Menu Model

```
protected $table="menus";

protected $fillable = [
    'resturant_id',
    'maincategory_id',
    'subcategory_id',
    'foodtype_id',
    'food_name',
    'slug',
    'food_price',
    'food_image'
];

public function mainCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MainCategory::class,'maincategory_id');
}

public function subCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class,'subcategory_id');
}
```

Problem is in my Controller

```
$data['main_category'] = MainCategory::with(['subCategories', 'menus'])
    ->whereHas('subCategories.foods', function ($q) use ($resturantid) {
        return $q->where('resturant_id', $resturantid);
    })
    ->whereHas('menus', function ($q) use ($resturantid) {
        return $q->where('resturant_id', $resturantid);
    })
    ->get();
```

I want to apply condition in subcategories `foods()` method where `resturant_id` is `resturant.id`.
But it is showing all the resturants data.
I have applied subquery with notation as well but did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is want you want, but could you try the following:

```
$data['main_category'] = MainCategory::with([
    'subCategories.foods' => function ($q) use ($resturantid) {
        $q->where('resturant_id', $resturantid);
    },
    'menus'
])
    ->whereHas('subCategories.foods', function ($q) use ($resturantid) {
        return $q->where('resturant_id', $resturantid);
    })
    ->whereHas('menus', function ($q) use ($resturantid) {
        return $q->where('resturant_id', $resturantid);
    })
    ->get();
```

This will only load the foods from the subCategories where the `resturant_id` matches the `$resturantid`